# How to make an animation in javascript/react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to change the opacity of an element after every 100 milliseconds after a click event. But it is not working. The function `change` is called after a click event. Here is my code:

```
function change (i) {
  var o:number = 0;
  setTimeout( function() {
    o = o + 0.1;
    document.querySelector("div.label").style.opacity = o;
    console.log("o = " + o);
  }, 100)
}
```

When I console log, the value of `o` is always 0.1. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: It looks like you're using typescript, should that tag be added? Also, do not use `document.querySelector("div.label")` with react. Prefer the use of `ref` and `useEffect` (or maybe `useLayoutEffect`)

Comment: Ok. But is there any javascript solution for this?

Comment: You are initializing the o variable inside the change function. Everytime you call it, o goes back to 0 and 0.1 after the timeout. And directly accessing the DOM isn't the way to go with React.

Comment: You can check Framer Motion if you're interested.

Comment: This question really needs some context of the surrounding React component. The code included heavily leads answerers towards solutions that wouldn't work well in the (not obvious) React setting.

Comment: It might be useful to consider CSS to solve your issue, transition (or animation) from `opacity: 0;` to `opacity: 1;` that lasts 1 second would result in the same thing. (You can use `step-start` or `step-end` if the reason you opted for solving this programatically in the first place was to avoid a smooth transition and instead wanted a 'jagged' effect.
edit: You would apply a class to the element that performs this animation when `on-click` was triggered on the desired element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using [setTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp), but I think you're looking for [setInterval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) method (if you want something to repeat itself).

Try :

```js
function change (i) {
  var o:number = 0;
  setInterval( function() {
    o = o + 0.1;
    document.querySelector("div.label").style.opacity = o;
    console.log("o = " + o);
  }, 100)
}
```

BE CAREFUL : you have to prevent your variable o to go beyond 1 (maximum opacity). You can use clearInterval().

Comment: What did you change here?

Comment: I used the setInterval() method instead of setTimeout()

Comment: Somehow I managed to do it. I also changed `opacity = o` to `opacity = o.toString()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the var *o* with the current opacity before increasing it:

```
function change (i) {
  var o:number = 0;
  setTimeout( function() {
    o = document.querySelector("div.label").style.opacity; // <-- ADD THIS
    o = o + 0.1;
    document.querySelector("div.label").style.opacity = o;
    console.log("o = " + o);
  }, 100)
}
```

Comment: What if the component re-renders? It will start all over again

Comment: In that case the var o need to be initialized outside the component and there is no need to set it equal to the current opacity